# вызов python скрипта по расписанию

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упускаю. С получением данных с api справился. Теперь хочу их получать через определенный промежуток времени, пусть будет каждую минуту. Решил воспользоваться `schedule`

```
import requests, time, datetime, json, schedule 


class Registration:

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'

    def get_registers(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        full_page = requests.get(self.url, auth=("admin","admin"))
        pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))
        a=sorted(pars, key=lambda pars: pars['time_visit'])
        count=0
        for i in a:
            if i['date_visit']==date:
                count +=1
                print(i["number_car"], i['time_visit'])

    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers())

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


reg = Registration()
reg.get_registers()
```

пытаюсь сделать так, но в итоге ошибка `TypeError: get_registers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Comment: Не силён в питоне, но, кажется, вам нужен метод `__init__` в классе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в дополнение к предыдущему ответу.
измените

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(reg.get_registers())
```

на

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(reg.get_registers)
```

Разница в следующем. В первом случае вы планируете выполнять результат reg.get_registers () (который равен None, поскольку вы ничего не возвращаете из этого метода) каждую минуту. Во втором случае вы планируете выполнять reg.get_registers самостоятельно каждую минуту.

Answer (score 2):

1. Проверь участок кода ниже. Возможно здесь лишние пробелы в начале строк. Или наоборот их не хватает. Скорее первый вариант

   ```
   schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers)

   while True:
       schedule.run_pending()
       time.sleep(1)
   ```
2. `TypeError: get_registers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`
   Первым аргументом в методе всегда (или почти всегда) является экземпляр класса.
   Очевидно, в строке ниже передача экземпляра в метод отсутствует.
   `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers())`
3. Предлагаю попробовать такой исправленный вариант

   ```
   import requests, time, datetime, json, schedule 


   class Registration:

       url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'

       def get_registers(self):
           now = datetime.datetime.now()
           date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
           full_page = requests.get(self.url, auth=("admin","admin"))
           pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))
           a=sorted(pars, key=lambda pars: pars['time_visit'])
           count=0
           for i in a:
               if i['date_visit']==date:
                   count +=1
                   print(i["number_car"], i['time_visit'])


   reg = Registration()
   schedule.every(1).minutes.do(reg.get_registers())

   while True:
       schedule.run_pending()
       time.sleep(1)
   ```